# Finding Accumulation Points of Set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am almost completely new to analysis. I am asked to show the accumulation points of $A = \{x\in\mathbb{Q}\enspace |\enspace x^2<2\}$. I have an intuition that the answer is $[\text{-}\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$ because I can't imagine any $``$gaps$"$ in this set. But I know this is nowhere near close to rigorous, and it is probably wrong. How do I prove that the proposed set has all the accumulation points of $A$? Please keep in mind that my working knowledge is very limited; this is not even an analysis course! I am familiar with the definition of an accumulation point and the Bolzano-Weirstrass Theorem, and that is about it.

Comment: Your "intuition"  is good...given epsiolon>0 and x in A, we can always find some rational point in [x-epsilon,x+epsilon] inters. A.  The interior of that set if empty, do you see this? (use the same argument).

Comment: @user123043 I thought that accumulation points did not need to be inside the set.

Comment: That is!! For instance, 0 (zero)  is an accumulation point in (0,1), but not interior.

Comment: @user123043 but the set of all accumulation points of (0,1) would include 0. Wouldn't it?

Comment: Your answer is correct; are you familiar with the density of rationals? That is, between any two distinct real numbers, there is a rational? If so, you can use the density of the rationals to provide the rigor you seek.

Comment: @Clayton I was not familiar with it, but I see your point. Thanks.

Comment: Correct; accumulation points need not be interior to a set (this means that an accumulation point does not necessarily have an open neighborhood around it contained entirely within the set). But it *does* mean that any open neighborhood of the point will intersect the set in question (so any neighborhood around $0$ will contain an interval of the form $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ which will intersect $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any point $x\in [-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$ and $\varepsilon >0$. Then, [by the density of the rational numbers](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-density-of-the-rational-irrational-numbers), we can find $y\in A$ such that $y\in ( [x-\varepsilon, x)\cup (x,x+\varepsilon])\cap \mathbb{Q}$ (recall the definition of acumulation point). So, $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$, i.e. $x\in A'$. If $x\not\in [-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$ then we cna find $\varepsilon>0$ such that $[x-\varepsilon, x+\varepsilon)\cap  A=\emptyset$.

Therefore $A'=[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$.

Comment: I see what you meant by "intersection" hint. Thanks a lot. I was not familiar with the density of rational numbers.